# Shinydashboard - DataTable width

Tags: r, shinydashboard

I want to create `shinydashboard` with plots&tables but when using `tabPanels`, `dataTable` is always outside the box. I tried to specify panel width with column and width parameter, but it only affects the plot.

Is there a way to restrict `datatable` so that it is displayed only within the `tabPanel`?
Thanks

[image]

Tab is rendered using this code:

```
dashboardBody(
tabItems(
  # First tab content
  tabItem(tabName = "dashboard_total_results",
          fluidRow(

            column(width = 15,

            tabBox(
              title = "Total deal results",
              id = "deal_res_tabset_1", height = "250px",
              tabPanel("Total revenue", 
                       plotlyOutput("total_revenue_plot"),
                       DT::dataTableOutput("total_revenue_table")),
              tabPanel("Total orders", 
                       plotlyOutput("total_orders_plot"),
                       DT::dataTableOutput("total_orders_table")),
              tabPanel("Total margin", 
                       plotlyOutput("total_margin_plot"),
                       DT::dataTableOutput("total_margin_table"))
            )

          )
          )
  )
```

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you would actually need to fix the `server` part and allow to scroll the columns. You should try something like this:

```
output$yourtablename= DT::renderDataTable(server = TRUE,{
  DT::datatable(df,
                extensions=c("Buttons",'Scroller'),
                options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip',
                               scrollY = 500,
                               scroller = TRUE,
                               scrollX=TRUE
                )
  )
})
```

Not sure that it will work because I was not able to reproduce your problem. Try and let me know.